# Unity Golf game physics and movement controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

So, i have a problem.
I am a beginner in unity and i want to create a Golf game.
I can code C# and i have a basic level in 3d modelling.
My Problem is I have no idea how the unity coding works. My idea is a system like in Golf It, you have a club that apears if you press the left mouse button and then it takes the y axis of your mouse and binds the club to that axis. as soon as you hit the ball it takes the velocity of the club and transports it on the golf ball. The physics are not that good in golf it cause you can't let the ball fly, doesn't matter how hard you hit. Thus i'd like to implement some realistic golf physics. (I am in highschool and thus i can calculate physic calculations).

I hope for someone who is a bit more expriecent and could at least give me some kind of idea how to solve that problem. Thanks already :)

btw. i already tried to search for tutorials and also did a try by myself but didn't come to any useful result. but i at least already modeled a club and ball and also a little golf track.

if it helps here is my idea for a script for the golf ball that waits on the impulse of the golf club (yeah it of course doesn't work).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      if (collision.gameObject.name == "golf_club")
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(Collision.impusle, 0, 0);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome new user.  Don't use Update.  Unity has many functions for when "a collision happens".

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

You'll have to become really familiar with all those.

I suggest *at first* get familiar with using the physics engine, you'll be surprised how well it works for golf.

Later you can write your own physics (use a coroutine).  You'll still likely use colliders *only as triggers* when you do that.  You'll have to learn all about that too.

Be aware that it can take ~ 1,000 hours of work to become familiar with the basics of Unity.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Do you have any tips on how I could learn how to create the script I mentioned above (else than the link you posted, which is already pretty helpful :)  I have full access to unity learn, so that shouldn't be a Problem.

Comment: Simply do this.  In your example code you're setting the velocity of a rigidbody every frame.  Do not do that. **Remove the rigidbody completely.**  Simply set **the position** of the object every frame.  It's really that simple.  To begin with just make a trivial script which (say) increases y by 1 centimeter every frame.  You will see the ball move upwards continually!  From there good luck.  You can easily read about Transform.position to set the position. It's that easy.  Please tick/vote answers BTW